# TimescaleDb: Can someone explain the concept of Hypertables?

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb

I'm learning timescaledb and it's concepts. But I'm unable to grasp Hypertables and it's purpose. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 2):

There's a pretty concise writeup of the different pieces of the timescaledb architecture here: https://docs.timescale.com/latest/introduction/architecture

The 10,000 foot view: A hypertable is an abstracted access layer to underlying tables holding slices of the overall timeseries data, which are called chunks.

This means you can query a single endpoint, which then routes to the appropriate underlying tables based on your query parameters, rather than having to join many smaller tables in the query.